# How to return a string without /n, as printing it

Tags: python, string, printing, return-type

I am doing an homework and I need to return a tree as string. I have solved the problem and when I print is all right. The problem is that the homework asks to return the string and when I return, it prints `/n` chars without considering them as new line.

If I print it this is the result:

```
04  
|
05  
|   
01  
|   
06  
|   
03
```

And this should be the string I have to return.

But if I use the return instead the print it returns this:

```
04  \n  |   \n  05  \n  |   \n  01  \n  |   \n  06  \n  |   
\n  03
```

This is the class I'm using:

```
class Albero:

  def __init__(self,V):

     self.id=V
     self.f=[]


  n=Albero("04")
  n1=Albero("05")
  n2=Albero("01")
  n3=Albero("06")
  n4=Albero("03")
  n.f=[n1]
  n1.f=[n2]
  n3.f=[n4]

 def treeLines(node,getInfo):
    nodeId,nodeChildren = getInfo(node)
    subNodes   = [treeLines(child,getInfo) for child in nodeChildren]
    widths     = [ len(childText[0]) for childText in subNodes ]
    totalWidth = sum(widths) + 2*len(widths) - 1
    totalWidth = max(totalWidth,len(nodeId))
    nodeLine   = nodeId.center(totalWidth," ")
    result     = [nodeLine]
    if not nodeChildren: return result
    linksLine   = "  ".join("|".center(width," ") for width in widths)
    linksLine   = linksLine.center(totalWidth," ")
    leftIndent  = linksLine.index("|") + 1
    rightIndent = linksLine[::-1].index("|") + 1
    spanWidth   = totalWidth - leftIndent - rightIndent - 1
    leftSpan    = nodeLine.index(nodeId)-leftIndent+(len(nodeId)-1)//2
    rightSpan   = spanWidth - leftSpan   
    spanLine    = " "*leftIndent + "_"*leftSpan + "|" + "_"*rightSpan + " "*rightIndent
    if len(nodeChildren) > 1 : result.append(spanLine)
    result.append(linksLine)
    maxHeight   = max(len(subNode) for subNode in subNodes)
    subNodes    = [ subNode + [" "*len(subNode[0])]*(maxHeight-len(subNode)) for subNode in subNodes ]
    result     += ["  ".join([subNode[i] for subNode in subNodes]).center(totalWidth," ") for i in range(maxHeight) ]
    return result  

def treeText(node,getInfo): return  "\n".join(treeLines(node,getInfo))

print( treeText(Albero.radice,lambda n:(n.id,n.f)) )
```

How can I return the string format as in the print ?

Comment: What happens when you print the returned value??

Comment: Please refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then create a [mcve] of your current code to show us, and show us its copy-pasted output as well as the expected output.

Comment: Share the code of printing you used, please.

Comment: The string is ok, leave the \n there. The important thing is that at the very end of your program you'll print it, and that's where \n is required.

Comment: Where/what  is `radice` in `Albero.radice`?